# Quartz.net scheduler Dev vs. Production Best Practice when use SQL as a store

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

According to the Quartz.net docs, it's strictly prohibited to point two instances of a scheduler to a single table set if they are not in a cluster mode. So, the question is how to deal with development if the app is already in production?

1. Disable persistence store for development
2. Make settings clustered (but time accuracy between production and dev machines should be within 1 sec... not so easy to handle?)
3. Make a separate copy of tables for development

How do you normally do this?

Comment: In response to @lahma comment on GitGub " Is this a question or some actual feature request?". This is a question if we already have a solution, and a feature request, if we don't.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the same database instance for development an production. I think that is dangerous because your development effort could left production out-of-order. I would go with option 3 or 1.

Comment: Right, I took an option 1 and it works and feels good. Thank you for your input.